# Responsive for Square shaped large screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using bootstrap for my site. The responsive according to different screens is good unless i see on a square shaped large screen. The content is centred on normal screen using padding top and i want it do be at the bottom when it is viewed on a square shaped screen, since it looks odd with the white space left below. How do i make it responsive to square shaped screens or say large screens ? I tried making the position relative to the bottom, it doesnt work !

Comment: [http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/) Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: @ishank Sticky footer is differ. I do not want it that way, i want slightly above the bottom. The content is not footer. I believed that position:relative and then a negative bottom should had worked and i dont why it doesn't :( The page again has sections, so i want it to be above this in one particular section

Comment: Please add some code snippets then.

Answer (score 4):

You can use media queries to target screens based on their pixel aspect ratio like this:

```
@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio:1/1) {
    /* square styles here */
}
```

Here's a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timmah/EgfuQ/3/)** of it in action.

This particular query only targets screens that are equal in height as in width *or taller*. If the aspect ratio is higher than 1:1, it means the screen is wider than it is tall.

If you want to target squares *precisely*, you can use :

```
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio:1/1) and (max-aspect-ratio:1/1) {
    /* square styles here */
}
```

I wouldn't recommend this though, as it will [only fire at that *exact* pixel ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#aspect-ratio), giving you no tolerance for varying display sizes, as you'll see in my Fiddle example above to this one. This could be making a lot of extra work for yourself.

Square screens are unique as normally a screen is either portrait or landscape in orientation, but a square screen can be neither. They are also quite rare as a display. Are you targeting Smartwatches perhaps?

---

**Update in Jan 2023**: Smartwatches have exploded in popularity and greatly-improved screen tech means displays are no longer restricted to oblongs like squares and rectangles. Displays can have rounded corners, be curved, fold open like a book, be circular etc.
All the more reason not to target exact sizes and ratios!